# Event Call is not changing bar colors for second half of the array

Tags: python, matplotlib, event-handling

This is an attempt to implement a bar chart where the bars change color based on the proximity of the events triggered by the mouse pointer's y axis to the bars in the plot.

One weird effect that was observed was, only the colors of the first half of the bars (from left to right) were changing and not the second half. Any idea why?

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax = axes[0]
#ax = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
#ax = fig.gca()
y = [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
x = [5401.565
    ,5635.739
    ,6092.861
    ,7245.169
    ,7586.334
    ,7708.000
    ,7516.826
    ,6872.729
    ,6080.949
    ,5303.580]
bars = ax.bar(y
         ,x
#        , color=color_map(data_normalizer(df.iloc[0][23:]))
       )
text=ax.annotate( ""
                 ,xy=(0,0)
                 ,xytext=(0,0)
                 ,textcoords="offset points"
                 ,xycoords = "figure points"
                )

horizontalLine = 0
lineLabel = ax.annotate(""
                       ,xy=(2010, 0) #(event.xdata, event.ydata)
                         ,xycoords = "data"
                       )

# Color map showing probability of proximity with the line, with increments of 10%
colorMap = ['#a50026','#d73027','#f46d43','#fdae61','#fee090','#e0f3f8','#abd9e9','#74add1','#4575b4','#313695']

def onmove(event):
    if (event.inaxes == ax):
        tx = ' x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' % (event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata)    
        if (len(ax.lines)>0):
            ax.lines[-1].remove()
        event.inaxes.axhline(event.ydata,0, 1, lw=1 )
        lineLabel.set_y(event.ydata)
        lineLabel.set_text("y = %.2f"%(event.ydata))
        text.set_text(tx)
        for bar in bars:
            bar_line_gap = bar.get_height() - event.ydata
            if(bar_line_gap < 0): # probability is 100%, show color 
                bar.set_color(colorMap[-1])
            else:
                proximityPercentageIndex = round(10*bar_line_gap/event.ydata)
                if (proximityPercentageIndex != 0):
                    bar.set_color(colorMap[proximityPercentageIndex])
                else:
                    bar.set_color('#000000')
    
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', onmove)
```

[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't run for me (proximityPercentageIndex evaluates to a float). Even if I convert it to an `int`, it gives index numbers way beyond 10. Please add relevant information, e.g. if this isn't Python 3 with the newest matplotlib version but something older.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has three issues:

1.`proximityPercentageIndex = round(10*bar_line_gap/event.ydata)`, times 9 not 10

2.`proximityPercentageIndex = round(10*bar_line_gap/event.ydata)`, should divide `bar.get_height()`, I guess

3.call `fig.canvas.draw()` inside `onmove()`, at least for matplotlib version in mydesktop.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax = axes[0]
#ax = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
#ax = fig.gca()
y = [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
x = [5401.565,5635.739,6092.861,7245.169,7586.334,7708.000,7516.826,6872.729,6080.949,5303.580]
bars = ax.bar(y,x)
text=ax.annotate( "",xy=(0,0),xytext=(0,0),textcoords="offset points",xycoords = "figure points")

horizontalLine = 0
lineLabel = ax.annotate("",xy=(2010, 0),xycoords = "data")

# Color map showing probability of proximity with the line, with increments of 10%
colorMap = ['#a50026','#d73027','#f46d43','#fdae61','#fee090','#e0f3f8','#abd9e9','#74add1','#4575b4','#313695']

def onmove(event):
    if (event.inaxes == ax):
        tx = ' x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' % (event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata)    
        if (len(ax.lines)>0):
            ax.lines[-1].remove()
        event.inaxes.axhline(event.ydata,0, 1, lw=1 )
        lineLabel.set_y(event.ydata)
        lineLabel.set_text("y = %.2f"%(event.ydata))
        text.set_text(tx)
        for bar in bars:
            bar_line_gap = bar.get_height() - event.ydata
            if(bar_line_gap < 0): # probability is 100%, show color 
                bar.set_color(colorMap[-1])
            else:
                # should times 9, not 10, as 0-9 got 10 integers
                # also should divide bar.get_height()
                proximityPercentageIndex = round(9*(bar_line_gap)/bar.get_height())
                if (proximityPercentageIndex != 0):
                    bar.set_color(colorMap[proximityPercentageIndex])
                else:
                    bar.set_color('#000000')
        fig.canvas.draw()
    
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', onmove)
```

[image]